# How can I set up admin user (to be able to check the server via GUI in an emergency?) in JBOSS EAP 7.1?

Tags: jboss, undertow

Can anyone please tell how can I set up admin user (to be able to check the server via GUI in an emergency? in JBOSS EAP 7.1?

Answer (score 0):

The default JBoss EAP configuration provides local authentication so that a user can access the management CLI on the local host without requiring authentication. User will not be able to access the JBoss admin console without adding a management user.

> Adding Management User

Management user can be used to access JBoss Admin console from which you can perform all setup related activities. To add a management user, change the directory to $JBOSS_HOME/bin. Run the following command:

## ./add-user.sh

1. Press ENTER to select the default option (a) to add a management user.
2. Enter the desired username and password. You will be prompted to confirm the password.
3. Enter a comma-separated list of groups to which the user belongs. If you do not want the user to belong to any groups, press ENTER to leave it blank. (Leave it Blank)
4. Select y/yes for rest of the questions
5. IMPORTANT: Make note of the secret value -> `<secret value="xxxxxxx" />`. Also, remember the password!!